# Is there a way to open up email client from a button click

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to open up a email client when the user clicks on the button. Is there a way to handle this for react js? Hopefully, something for both iOS, android and web.

```
const Sponsors = ({id, imgStart, buttonLabel, headLine, description, alt}) => {
  return (
      <>
          <InfoContainer id={id}>
              <InfoWrapper>
                  <InfoRow imgStart={imgStart}>
                      <Column1>
                          <TextWrapper>
                              <Heading>
                                  {headLine}
                              </Heading>
                              <ImgWrap>
                                  <Img src={img} alt={alt} style={{width:"150px", height:"150px"}}/>
                              </ImgWrap>
                          </TextWrapper>
                      </Column1>
                      <Column2>
                          <Subtitle>
                              {description}
                          </Subtitle>
                          <BtnWrap>
                              <Button to="">{buttonLabel}</Button>
                          </BtnWrap>
                      </Column2>
                  </InfoRow>
              </InfoWrapper>
          </InfoContainer>
      </>
  );
};

export default Sponsors;
```

Comment: Did you consider URLs similar to `mailto:john.doe@example.com` ?

Comment: When you say you want this to also work for iOS and Android do you mean in a browser on these OS's, or are you using React-native and want it to work there as well? Would an URL (anchor href) for a [mailto](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/mailto-links/) link work for you?

Comment: I tried the mailto way but it doesnt open up the email client itself for me. not too sure what i was doing wrong back there. It's all to be opened on the OS's